# Yii2 compareValidator when

Tags: yii2, comparevalidator

During user input validation I would like to compare an attribute with a value.

I have this code:

```
['ao_id', 'compare', 'when' => function($model) {
            return $model->lqp_id == 24 || $model->lqp_id == 26 || $model->lqp_id == 46;
        }, 'compareValue' => 50],
```

It works (however only when `'enableClientValidation' => false`), but is it possible, to show rather the name of the foreign attribute somehow? Because it doesn't help much if the user is getting an error message that outer surface (ao_id) must be 50. Nobody has a clue what does it mean, because in the dropdown you see only the names and not the ids. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `message` key where you define your own message that will be displayed instead of default one.

Comment: Thank you very much, Bizley!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want your conditional validation to work on the client-side too (when `enableClientValidation=>true`), then add the `whenClient` property which contains the javascript code that will do the validation.

Second, you can use the `message` property to specify a custom validation error.

```
[
    'ao_id', 
    'compare', 
    'when' => function ($model) {
        return $model->lqp_id == 24 || $model->lqp_id == 26 || $model->lqp_id == 46;
    }, 
    'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
        return $('#lqp_id').val() == '24' || $('#lqp_id').val() == '26' || $('#lqp_id').val() == '46';
    }", 
    'compareValue' => 50, 
    'message'=>'ao_id must be 50 when lqp_id is 24, 26 or 46'
]
```

Attention: be sure to check and change the id of the input field `$('#lqp_id')` as this is most likely different to my example.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer as well. You have solved both of my problems, so I wanted to give you the points, but Bizley was faster and the main question was `message`. However I was hoping that there is a built-in function that translates somehow the id automagically to a corresponding name. But `message` is also not bad at the moment.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no function that can fetch the `name` corresponding with the `id` within the rule array itself, however you can make a custom validation function where you _can_. If you would like to see an example, let me know and I will update the answer. Oh, and a +1 would be greatly appreciated if you are happy with the answer ;)